# maven compiler plugin conflict with kotlin maven plugin

Tags: java, kotlin, mapstruct

I'm setting up kotlin to springboot project, for now I want to support both java and kotlin. My project also have lombok & mapstruct as normal. 
When I build maven I got this issue:

```java
Internal error in the mapping processor: java.lang.RuntimeException: 
javax.annotation.processing.FilerException: Attempt to recreate a file for type com.mypackage.converter.NotificationConverterImpl   at org.mapstruct.ap.internal.processor.MapperRenderingProcessor.createSourceFile(MapperRenderingProcessor.java:59)      at org.mapstruct.ap.internal.processor.MapperRenderingProcessor.writeToSourceFile(MapperRenderingProcessor.java:39)     
at org.mapstruct.ap.internal.processor.MapperRenderingProcessor.process(MapperRenderingProcessor.java:29)   
at org.mapstruct.ap.internal.processor.MapperRenderingProcessor.process(MapperRenderingProcessor.java:24)   
at org.mapstruct.ap.MappingProcessor.process(MappingProcessor.java:338)     
at org.mapstruct.ap.MappingProcessor.processMapperTypeElement(MappingProcessor.java:318)    
at org.mapstruct.ap.MappingProcessor.processMapperElements(MappingProcessor.java:267)   
at org.mapstruct.ap.MappingProcessor.process(MappingProcessor.java:166)     
at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.processing.JavacProcessingEnvironment.callProcessor(JavacProcessingEnvironment.java:980)    
at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.processing.JavacProcessingEnvironment.discoverAndRunProcs(JavacProcessingEnvironment.java:896)      
at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.processing.JavacProcessingEnvironment$Round.run(JavacProcessingEnvironment.java:1222)   
at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.processing.JavacProcessingEnvironment.doProcessing(JavacProcessingEnvironment.java:1334)    
at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.main.JavaCompiler.processAnnotations(JavaCompiler.java:1258)    
at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.main.JavaCompiler.compile(JavaCompiler.java:936)    
at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.api.JavacTaskImpl.lambda$doCall$0(JavacTaskImpl.java:104)   
at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.api.JavacTaskImpl.handleExceptions(JavacTaskImpl.java:147)      
at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.api.JavacTaskImpl.doCall(JavacTaskImpl.java:100)    
at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.api.JavacTaskImpl.call(JavacTaskImpl.java:94)   
at org.codehaus.plexus.compiler.javac.JavaxToolsCompiler.compileInProcess(JavaxToolsCompiler.java:125)      
at org.codehaus.plexus.compiler.javac.JavacCompiler.performCompile(JavacCompiler.java:169)      
at org.apache.maven.plugin.compiler.AbstractCompilerMojo.execute(AbstractCompilerMojo.java:823)     
at org.apache.maven.plugin.compiler.CompilerMojo.execute(CompilerMojo.java:129)     
at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:134)    
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:208)      
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:154)      
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:146)      
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)     
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)      
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build(SingleThreadedBuilder.java:51)    
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:128)      
at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:309)   
at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:194)   
at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:107)     
at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:955)     
at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:290)      
at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:194)    
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)   
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)     
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)     
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)   
at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:289)      
at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:229)      
at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:415)    
at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:356)    
at org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:47)  
Caused by: javax.annotation.processing.FilerException: Attempt to recreate a file for type com.alibaba.logistics.notification.gateway.converter.NotificationConverterImpl   
at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.processing.JavacFiler.checkNameAndExistence(JavacFiler.java:724)    
at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.processing.JavacFiler.createSourceOrClassFile(JavacFiler.java:489)      
at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.processing.JavacFiler.createSourceFile(JavacFiler.java:426)     
at org.mapstruct.ap.internal.processor.MapperRenderingProcessor.createSourceFile(MapperRenderingProcessor.java:56)      ... 44 more  
[INFO] 1 error
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
```

Here is my pom

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <parent>
        <artifactId>iot-notification-gateway</artifactId>
        <groupId>com.mycompany.iot</groupId>
        <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </parent>
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <artifactId>notification-gateway-service</artifactId>
    <properties>
        <spring-boot-starter-hsf.version>2.2.8.2-1.SB2</spring-boot-starter-hsf.version>
        <org.mapstruct.version>1.3.0.Final</org.mapstruct.version>
        <kotlin.version>1.5.10</kotlin.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.mycompany.iot</groupId>
            <artifactId>notification-gateway-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.groovy</groupId>
            <artifactId>groovy-all</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.mycompany.iot.share</groupId>
            <artifactId>notification-gateway-client</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.8-SNAPSHOT</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <version>1.18.20</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- mapstruct -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mapstruct</groupId>
            <artifactId>mapstruct</artifactId>
            <version>${org.mapstruct.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mapstruct</groupId>
            <artifactId>mapstruct-processor</artifactId>
            <version>${org.mapstruct.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- mapstruct -->

        <dependency>
            <groupId>joda-time</groupId>
            <artifactId>joda-time</artifactId>
            <version>2.10.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.mycompany.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-apphealth-starter</artifactId>
            <version>${springboot-cloud-starter.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <!--Kotline-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jetbrains.kotlin</groupId>
            <artifactId>kotlin-maven-noarg</artifactId>
            <version>${kotlin.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jetbrains.kotlin</groupId>
            <artifactId>kotlin-reflect</artifactId>
            <version>${kotlin.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jetbrains.kotlin</groupId>
            <artifactId>kotlin-stdlib</artifactId>
            <version>${kotlin.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- testing -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.spockframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spock-core</artifactId>
            <version>1.3-groovy-2.5</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.spockframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spock-spring</artifactId>
            <version>1.3-groovy-2.5</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.javassist</groupId>
            <artifactId>javassist</artifactId>
            <version>3.25.0-GA</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
            <artifactId>mockito-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.18.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.powermock</groupId>
            <artifactId>powermock-api-mockito2</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.0-beta.5</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.powermock</groupId>
            <artifactId>powermock-module-junit4</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.0-beta.5</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- testing -->
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <defaultGoal>compile</defaultGoal>
        <finalName>iot-notification-gateway</finalName>
        <plugins>
            <!--Kotline-->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.jetbrains.kotlin</groupId>
                <artifactId>kotlin-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>kapt</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>kapt</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <sourceDirs>
                                <sourceDir>src/main/kotlin</sourceDir>
                                <sourceDir>src/main/java</sourceDir>
                            </sourceDirs>
                            <annotationProcessorPaths>
                                <path>
                                    <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                                    <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                                    <version>1.18.2</version>
                                </path>
                                <path>
                                    <groupId>org.mapstruct</groupId>
                                    <artifactId>mapstruct-processor</artifactId>
                                    <version>${org.mapstruct.version}</version>
                                </path>
                            </annotationProcessorPaths>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <id>compile</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>compile</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <sourceDirs>
                                <sourceDir>${project.basedir}/src/main/kotlin</sourceDir>
                                <sourceDir>${project.basedir}/src/main/java</sourceDir>
                            </sourceDirs>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <id>test-compile</id>
                        <goals> <goal>test-compile</goal> </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <sourceDirs>
                                <sourceDir>${project.basedir}/src/test/kotlin</sourceDir>
                                <sourceDir>${project.basedir}/src/test/java</sourceDir>
                            </sourceDirs>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <configuration>
                    <compilerPlugins>
                        <plugin>jpa</plugin>
                        <plugin>no-arg</plugin>
                    </compilerPlugins>
                    <pluginOptions>
                        <option>no-arg:annotation=lombok.NoArgsConstructor</option>
                    </pluginOptions>
                </configuration>
                <dependencies>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.jetbrains.kotlin</groupId>
                        <artifactId>kotlin-maven-noarg</artifactId>
                        <version>${kotlin.version}</version>
                    </dependency>
                </dependencies>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <executable>false</executable>
                    <excludeDevtools>true</excludeDevtools>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>repackage</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <configuration>
                            <tasks>
                                <unzip
                                        src="${project.build.directory}/${project.build.finalName}.${project.packaging}"
                                        dest="${project.build.directory}/{$finalName}" />
                            </tasks>
                        </configuration>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>run</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.gmavenplus</groupId>
                <artifactId>gmavenplus-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.8.1</version>
                <extensions>true</extensions>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>compile</goal>
                            <goal>compileTests</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <configuration>
                    <testSources>
                        <testSource>
                            <directory>${pom.basedir}/src/test/java</directory>
                            <includes>
                                <include>**/*.groovy</include>
                            </includes>
                        </testSource>
                    </testSources>

                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.0-M3</version>
                <configuration>
                    <argLine>${argLine}</argLine>
                    <properties>
                        <property>
                            <name>listener</name>
                            <value>com.mycompany.iot.notification.gateway.config.FailFastListener</value>
                        </property>
                    </properties>
                    <includes>
                        <!-- By default only files ending in 'Test' will be included, so also include support for Spock style naming convention -->
                        <!-- Oddly enough for Groovy files, *Spec.groovy does not work, but *Spec.java does -->
                        <include>**/*Test.java</include>
                        <include>**/*Spec.java</include>
                        <include>**/*Spec.groovy</include>
                    </includes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                        <source>11</source>
                        <target>11</target>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <!-- Replacing default-compile as it is treated specially by maven -->
                    <execution>
                        <id>default-compile</id>
                        <phase>none</phase>
                    </execution>
                    <!-- Replacing default-testCompile as it is treated specially by maven -->
                    <execution>
                        <id>default-testCompile</id>
                        <phase>none</phase>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <id>java-compile</id>
                        <phase>compile</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>compile</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <id>java-test-compile</id>
                        <phase>test-compile</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>testCompile</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
        <resources>
            <resource>
                <directory>src/main/java</directory>
                <includes>
                    <include>**/*Mapper.xml</include>
                </includes>
                <filtering>true</filtering>
            </resource>
            <resource>
                <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
                <filtering>true</filtering>
                <excludes>
                    <exclude>fonts/*</exclude>
                </excludes>
            </resource>
            <resource>
                <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
                <filtering>false</filtering>
                <includes>
                    <include>fonts/*</include>
                </includes>
            </resource>
        </resources>
    </build>

</project>
```

I guess the kotlin-maven-plugin try to generate mapper first then when maven-compiler-plugin run it will throw this exception about `file recreate`. I faced same issue when I compile another java projects without clean it. 
To fix this I just comment out the kotline maven plugin but then my `kt` code is no longer compiled. \

Any guys have faced this issue?

Comment: How are your dependencies? You specifically don't use default-compile so maven-compile is executed after the kotlin-maven-plugin. Is it feasible to reverse that order? Is com.mypackage.converter.NotificationConverterImpl defined in a Java or Kotlin source?

Comment: hi @kutschkem NotificationConverterImpl is a java source, from console i see maven execute exactly the order that i define, it run kotlin plugin first to compile the java + kotline source, it also trigger mapstruct to generate impl classes. but when manven compiler plugin run it try to regenerate impl classes again so it lead to the issue "recreate file". in my understanding, it should skip that step, right? i setup project base on guideline of kotlin

Comment: I don't know kotlin, but if that already compiles the java sources I think you can skip maven-compiler plugin.

Comment: hi @kutschkem
i tried to comment out maven-compile plugin but look like maven will trigger default maven compile and still face same issue